# Can KDE software be installed on GNOME?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, kde

So I want to get started with linux. I started reading a few books on it and they have
taught me a good amount. Now in an example on one of the books it shows this command:

apt-cache search screenshot | grep KDE

So now im wondering, as I plan to install Mint Cinnamon, would I replace the KDE with 
GNOME and would I be able to install a KDE application on GNOME. Thanks

(Cinnamon is basically a custom GNOME 3.x right?)

Comment: YES kde software can be put on GNOME and vice versa.  GNOME Software can be put on KDE.  As a side note screenshot only an app.  GNOME uses screenshot, and KDE uses Shutter or KSnapshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can install every package you need install on gnome:

```
apt-get install k3b
```

`k3b` is a CD/DVD burner and Audio ripper.

Of course, on first installation of KDE application such as `k3b`, `apt-get` first installs some basic dependencies, for following installations such as `kmail` or `kate`, `apt-get` doen't need to re-install the same dependencies.